# What are this Spring version names?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, versioning

When I work with various parts of the sping framework I see this version names like *Einstein*, *Darwin*, *Celsius* etc.

Some examples can be found here:

- https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#learn
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters

I learned, that spring boot uses this version as some kind of selector if I use `spring-boot-starter-parent` in my `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

I also learnd, that sometimes things start to break if I change them. But what do this names realy mean? Is there an order? Is *Einstein* newer than *Celsisus*? What's the relation to the version numbers, like the one of `spring-boot-starter-parent`?

Comment: They are in alphabetical order. E is after D

Answer (score 4):

The names `Celsius`, `Darwin`, `Einstein` etc are release names of the `Spring Cloud Stream App Starters` project. The documentation for the same can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/). They are in alphabetical order, ie `Einstein` is the newer than `Darwin` (Similar to Android's release naming as Lollipop,  Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo etc).

Every Spring project has its own release name convention, with [Spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/) having 1.x.x, 2.x.x and so on, [Spring cloud stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/) having Chelsea, Ditmars, Elmhurst and so on. There is no direct relation of `Einstein` with the version number of `spring-boot-starter-parent` as such, but few features might be dependant on the version of Spring boot, and if there are any, they would be mentioned in their respective documentations.

Comment: That's a good answer. Additionally, it's worth to know, that the easiest way of getting your Spring dependencies for the project in correct versions is generating the buid file at (https://start.spring.io/). This will also apply the required dependency management plugins for you.

Answer (score 1):

On top of other answers, you can check [Spring cloud stream app starters releases page](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/app-starters-release/releases) on GitHub.
It nicely presents all releases and versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, each of them is a name for a set of library and version. Sometimes, changing the name will break your build as certain library/version is not in (or as not expected).